# Replace value in a span tag with percentage

Tags: javascript, html

i want the value of e to be a percentage. If value of e is 30 i want to display e as 1.5 that is 5% of 30. Below is the function and html that displays e, thanks for your help.

```
    function g(e) {
        p = e;
        for (var t = document.getElementsByClassName("aaz"), n = 0; n < t.length; n++) 
        t[n].textContent = e
    }
    
    <span class="aaz">0</span>
```

I know there's something like this i can use but don't know how to use it "Math.round(e/100*5)"

Comment: And what's your question about this? Anything not working with the given code?

Comment: The code works to show the value of "e". What i want is to change the valu of e to a percentage. I want the value of e to be 5% of the value. I know i can use something like this Math.round(e/100*5); but don't know how to use it

Comment: ??? Just replace `e` with `Math.round(e/100*5);`.

Comment: Ok will try that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want write function that change number that into span with certain percentage, try this

```js
const aaz = +document.querySelector(".aaz").textContent
const result = document.querySelector(".result")

function g(e) {
  p = e * 0.05
  result.textContent = p
}
g(aaz)
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.aaz {
  display: block;
  margin: 1rem;
}
.result {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
    <span class="aaz">30</span>
    <span class="result"></span>
```

Comment: This worked, thanks a bunch